# First person jump only works at certain angles

Tags: unity, c#, first-person-shooter, jumping, character-controller

I'm making a basic 3D First Person project using the movement code below, but I can only jump at a certain angle.

How can I fix this so that my character can jump anywhere?

````cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("References")]
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Transform head;
    public Camera camera;

    [Header("Configurations")]
    public float walkSpeed;
    public float runSpeed;
    public float jumpSpeed;

    [Header("Runtime")]
    Vector3 newVelocity;
    bool isGrounded = false;
    bool isJumping = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() {
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 2f);
        newVelocity = Vector3.up * rb.velocity.y;
        float speed = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) ? runSpeed : walkSpeed;
        newVelocity.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
        newVelocity.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;

        if (isGrounded) {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !isJumping) {
                newVelocity.y = jumpSpeed;
                isJumping = true;
            }
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        rb.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(newVelocity);

        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out RaycastHit hit, 1f))
            isGrounded = true;
        else isGrounded = false;
    }

    void LateUpdate() {
        Vector3 e = head.eulerAngles;
        e.x -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * 2f;
        e.x = RestrictAngle(e.x, -85, 85f);
        head.eulerAngles = e;
    }
        
    public static float RestrictAngle(float angle, float angleMin, float angleMax) {
        if (angle > 180)
        angle -= 360;
        else if (angle < -180)
        angle += 360;

        if (angle > angleMax)
            angle = angleMax;
        if (angle < angleMin)
            angle = angleMin;

        return angle;
    }

    void OnCollisionStay(Collision col) {
        isGrounded = true;
        isJumping = false;
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision col) {
        isGrounded = false;
    }
    
}
```
````

Comment: Your `isGrounded` logic seems a bit off, since it should be possible to trigger multiple jumps before the player is 1f off the ground with how you set to to true/ false. Also for what reason are you using both the Collision methods and a raycast for ground detection?

Comment: TBH i was following a tutorial just to start

Comment: Your raycast checks for hitting things downwards but OnCollisionStay will as well be true when you hit vertical walls. It depends for your game if wall jumps are a thing or not.

Comment: they are not, what do I edit to make it work because without the raycast code it still doesn't work

Comment: oh wait without the raycast it does work

Comment: although the jumping is really buggy, is there a way to make it smoother and more consistant

Comment: What is not smooth? The movement, the time it takes to react to your keypress, incosistency?

Comment: Keep in mind as well that `Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * 2f` returns a value at most between -2 to 2, which is basically nothing compared to the head transform. Please describe how you want your jump to actually work. So from just guess reading, I would say it always get clipped at the -85 / 85 range

Comment: @Zibelas the time it takes and the inconsistency

Comment: For example `Input.GetKeyDown` only is true a single frame. If you press is before you are grounded, your character won't jump until you repress the space bar.